# Can I use date calculation inside NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, nstimeinterval

I have a `NSDate` attribute in a `Drug` entity in `CoreData`, called `expiringDate`, and I need to fetch all the entities with a date within an interval of 30 days before `expiringDate`.
I can't figure out if and how I can include this kind of calculation inside `NSPredicate`.
I'd like to avoid to use a new attribute, kind of `thirtyDayFromExpiryDate`, inside the DB structure, obtain the date by `NSTimeInterval` calculation and use that in the predicate to get rid of the issue.
Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: @fraguida did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to return all results with:

```
expiryDate > [NSDate date] && aMonthToExpityDate <= [NSDate date]
```

where

```
aMonthToExpiryDate = expiryDate - 30 days
```

So you can simplify rewrite your query as:

```
expiryDate > [NSDate date] && (expiryDate - 30 days) <= [NSDate date]
```

or

```
expirayDate > [NSDate date] && (expiryDate <= [NSDate date] + 30 days)
```

Which you can now use in a predicate since the calculation is static:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"expiryDate BETWEEN (%@, %@)",
                          [NSDate date],
                          [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:k30Days]];
```

Comment: I have to fetch all the objects with expiryDate > [NSDate date] && aMonthToExpityDate <= [NSDate date] or if you prefer all the objects with [NSDate date] BETWEEN {aMonthToExpiryDate, expiryDate}. The problem is I don't have aMonthToExpiryDate (that is expiryDate - 30 days) to include it in the predicate, and I need to say to NSFetchedResultsController to calculate it on fly. Can I? How?